Sequence to Sequence LSTM for classification
I have a dataset with two columns:
past_events, future_events.
The past_events is a sequence of 53 numerical codes like this
'198', '2000', '197', '85903',...
While the future_events is a sequence of 52 numerical codes like this
'345', '200', '8904', '23765',...
Each code represents an event (the codes are in chronological order).
I have almost 3000 rows in this dataset.
I want to build an LSTM that takes the sequence of the past_events in input and, for the output, gives a sequence of 52 events that are the prediction for the future_events.
Since each code represents an event, in future_events there may appear codes that are not present in the past_events and some codes may appear only in a few rows, so only for a few numbers of sequence.
It is my first time doing this kind of problem. If it is sequence to value I could do it, but with sequence to sequence with this kind of classification I don't know how to build this model.
Can you give me some examples or some site in which this kind of problem is explained?
This is my attempt to build the LSTM, but it didn't work
input_1 = Input(shape=sequence_length)

lstm_out = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(input_1)
lstm_out = Dropout(0.2)(lstm_out)
lstm_out = LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(lstm_out)
lstm_out = Dropout(0.2)(lstm_out)
lstm_out = LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(lstm_out)
lstm_out = Dropout(0.2)(lstm_out)

lstm_out = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :52, :])(lstm_out)

# Attention mechanism
attention = Attention()([lstm_out, lstm_out])

dense_out = TimeDistributed(Dense(128, activation='relu'))(attention)
dense_out = Dropout(0.2)(dense_out)

output_layer = TimeDistributed(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))(dense_out)

The best I could obtain was that the predictions were all the same numerical code, so for example 52 '367'
